# Hyperledger composer playground error on IBM Blockchain Platform

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to learn about hyperledger composer by going through the tutorials. Everything works on the playground so I followed the [tutorial](https://ibm-blockchain.github.io/) and created a cluster with bluemix.

http://184.172.229.160:31080/

I was testing the hosted playground and I notice all transactions, even if deployed with a sample network like trade-network, returns error saying the asset or participant does not exist

`Error: Object with ID 'tradingSymbol:ABC' in collection with ID 'Asset:org.acme.trading.Commodity' does not exist`

Any advice on troubleshooting the above error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that you don't need the `tradingSymbol:` prefix and that your asset ID is just `ABC`.

Comment: thats right. wondering why it works in playground but not on the hosted version of composer though...

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that Composer Playground use, in your case, `tradingSymbol:ABC` as the ID, so when you try to retrieve an object you must consider the ID like `tradingSymbol:ABC`.

If you want to use the ID `ABC` you must erase `tradingSymbol:ABC` when you create the object using the playground and write just `ABC`. I know it is a little bit tricky.